# limit number of posts in single page

Tags: php, pagination

I wanna limit number of posts on page. Here is code i am using :-

```
<?php 
                            $query="select * from namedb";
                            $result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
                            while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                            {
                            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $r['title']?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r['comment']?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r['cgender']?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r['cnumerology']?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r['creligion']?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
```

and using this code for pagination

```
<?php
                                    $query="select * from namedb";
                                    $result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
                                    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
                                    $pages=ceil($count/10);
                                    for($i=1;$i<=$pages;$i++) { ?>
                                        <a href="links.php?p=<?php echo $i; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $i;?></a>
                                <?php } ?>
```

There are 21 posts in my database and 20 posts are showing on my page but pagination is showing as 1 2 3 and 2nd & 3rd page is showing same data. how to fix it.

I wanna show 30 records per page and if page has less then 30 records then pagination will not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in your code that actually does any paging when you get the names from the database. Change the first part to the following code and  keep the 2nd part of the code same.

```
$page = 1;
$per_page = 10;
if(isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric($_GET['p']) )
    $page= $_GET['p'];
$offset = ($page -1) * $per_page;

$query="select * from namedb LIMIT $offset, $per_page  ";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{ ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $r['title']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['comment']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['cgender']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['cnumerology']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['creligion']?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: on main page showing an error Notice: Undefined index: p in E:\xampp\htdocs\nydb1\sports.php on line 27

but when i click on pagination then everything is fine. Please let me know how to solve on main page too?

Comment: Changed the answer. Check now and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the MySQL `LIMIT` command. For instance, by writing

```
SELECT * FROM namedb LIMIT 0,30
SELECT * FROM namedb LIMIT 30,30
SELECT * FROM namedb LIMIT 60,30
...
```

you will get the first, second, third batch of 30 results. Here, the first number is giving the offset (note that it starts with 0, so 30 actually gives the 31st result), while the second number tells how many entries will be returned.

You can integrate this into the first part of your script by calculating the offset from the GET parameter `p`, like so:

```
 $length_of_page = 30;

 $page = intval($_GET["p"]);
 $offset = $page * $length_of_page;
 $query = "SELECT * FROM namedb LIMIT $offset, $length_of_page"
```

The `intval` function makes sure that you really insert a number into the query. This is important to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
<?php 
                            $query="select * from namedb limit 0,30";
                            $result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
                            while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                            {
                            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $r['title']?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r['comment']?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r['cgender']?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r['cnumerology']?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r['creligion']?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
```